# Django: Changing the url of an optional ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models

Via signals I check if my model belongs to a category. If it is, I want to change my optional ImageField to a specific url.

How can this be achieved? Code below doesnt work, I get "cannot set attribute" error as it is an optional field and it was blank as I saved it.

Here is my sample model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    category = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
    poster = models.ImageField(u"Poster", blank=True)
```

and my post save signal:

```
def post_poster(instance, **kwargs):
        if instance.category == 1 #a specific category
            instance.poster.url = u'/media/special_image_for_1.png'
            instance.save()
    except MovieCat.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Comment: This is not a proper python syntax, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what problem you're having (does that code work?), so there are two problems in your code. Firstly, you probably don't want to be saving in a post-save signal (infinite loop, anyone?). <s>Secondly, you've got an indentation issue (you need to indent after the `if`).</s>

The way you probably want to do this is with [`Model.clean()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.clean).

Define a `clean` method on your model like this:

```
def clean(self):
  if instance.category == 1 #a specific category
    instance.poster.url = u'/media/special_image_for_1.png'
```

Comment: excuse my rush, now I editted the problem part and set the indention correctly.