# Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField returning 404 in production

Tags: django, nginx, django-models, python-imaging-library, django-media

I have a Django app where users can upload images and can have a processed version of the images if they want. and the processing function returns the path, so my approach was

```
model2.processed_image = processingfunction( model1.uploaded_image.path)
```

and as the processing function returns path here's how it looks in my admin view

[image]

not like the normally uploaded images

[image]

In my machine it worked correctly and I always get a 404 error for the processed ones while the normally uploaded is shown correctly when I try to change the url of the processed from

```
myurl.com/media/home/ubuntu/Eyelizer/media/path/to/the/image 
 to 
myurl.com/media/path/to/the/image
```

so how can I fix this ? is there a better approach to saving the images manually to the database ?

I have the same function but returns a Pil.image.image object and I've tried many methods to save it in a model but I didn't know how so I've made the function return a file path.

I think the problem is from nginx where I define the media path.

should/can I override the url attribute of the processedimage? 
making something like

```
model.processed_image.url = media/somefolder/filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is a bit different from @Xyres's, I thought xyres's would make a duplicate of the existing image and create a new one and when I tried overriding the URL attribute it returned an error of

> can't set the attribute

but when I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189114/cant-set-imagefield-url-attribute) question and [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15590) ticket I tried making this and it worked

```
model2.processed_image = processingfunction(model1.uploaded_image.path)
full_path = model2.processed_image.path
model2.processed_image.name = full_path.split('media')[1]
```

so that explicitly making the URL `media/path/to/image` and cut out all of the unneeded parts like `home/ubuntu` and stuff

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a simpler and better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the PIL Image directly, create a [`django.core.files.File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/file/).

Example:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File

img_io = BytesIO() # create a BytesIO object to temporarily save the file in memory
img = processingfunction( model1.uploaded_image.path)
img.save(img_io, 'PNG') # save the PIL image to the BytesIO object

img_file = File(thumb_io, name='some-name.png') # create the File object
# you can use the `name` from `model1.uploaded_image` and use 
# that above

# finally, pass the image file to your model field
model2.processed_image = img_file
```

To avoid repetition of this code, it would be a good idea to keep this code in `processingfunction` and return the `File` object directly from there.

Comment: and will Django handle the file attribute directly as it's normally uploaded

Comment: and wouldn't i have a duplicate of the processed file ?

Comment: @Ammarrady Yes, Django will handle the file as if it's normally uploaded. Regarding duplicate file, don't save the processed file to the disk yourself, let Django handle that.

Comment: thanks for your help, your answer was really great and this approach is good, I tried a different one you can check it.